# how save Grid Background in my app

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

how seve the grid background after choose image by choose image task

EX:

```csharp
 private void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
 {
     if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
     {
         bmp = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
         bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
         ImageBrush img = new ImageBrush();
         img.ImageSource = bmp;
         LayoutRoot.Background = img;

         //Save grid Background 
    }
}
```

help me please
thank you :)

Note: 'Save' means that when the application open next time 
 be 'grid backgrund' the same background chosen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.. In the example i have used a button to activate the `PhotoChooserTask`. The XAML is like this.

**XAML**

```xaml
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Button Name="btnSet" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="Set Image" Click="btnSet_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Click event for the button.

**C#**

```jcsharp
private void btnSet_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PhotoChooserTask photoTask = new PhotoChooserTask();
    photoTask.Completed += photoTask_Completed;
    photoTask.PixelHeight = 1280;
    photoTask.PixelWidth = 768;
    photoTask.Show();
}
```

In the `photoTask_Completed` event handler you can save the image to the `IsolatedStorage`

```jcsharp
void photoTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {
        using (var isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (isoStore.FileExists(fileName))
            {
                isoStore.DeleteFile(fileName);
            }
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream targetStream = isoStore.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];
                int bytesRead = -1;

                while ((bytesRead = e.ChosenPhoto.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    targetStream.Write(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the `OnNavigatedTo` event you can load the image from `IsolatedStorage` and set it as the background.

```jcsharp
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    byte[] data;

    using (var isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        if (isoStore.FileExists(fileName))
        {
            using(IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = isoStore.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                data = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            }

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
            bmp = new BitmapImage();
            bmp.SetSource(ms);
            ImageBrush img = new ImageBrush();
            img.ImageSource = bmp;
            LayoutRoot.Background = img;
        }
    }
}
```

The variable `fileName` holds the name of the image saved to the `IsolatedStorage`. The image is overwritten every time you select a new image from the library. Hope this helps.

Comment: thank yooooooooooooooooooooooou very veryyyyyyyyyyyyyyy much ^_^

Answer (score 1):

try this:

XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush x:Name="imgsrc"></ImageBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

CS:

```
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {
        BitmapImage Bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        Bitmap.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
        imgsrc.ImageSource = Bitmap;
    }
```

for Saving image you would be needed to use isolatedstorage. You would be needed to save your image in Isolatedstorage and have a isolatedsettings variabe for saving the state of the image whether you have choosen any image or not.

If yes then get image from there otherwise no action would be needed, here is a good example from you can have reference for saving and Retriving image from Isolatedstorage [Isolated Storage - Read and Save Images](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage---read-and-save-images)